# How to embed/use ICC color profiles using svgwrite?

Tags: svg, colors, icc, svgwrite

I believe that there is no API method to associate/embed ICC profiles using svgwrite (correct me if I'm wrong) but is it possible to do this by e.g. manually setting parameters and so forth?

I'm a bit lost with the details about ICC and SVG in general, but: it sounds like the ["color-profile" element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/color.html#ColorProfileElement) is deprecated and one should use a CSS property @color-profile (I'm not sure how to do that with svgwrite either) to define the profile, and then perhaps one could set the color_profile parameter on an object in svgwrite to refer to that profile?

When referring to the profile via svgwrite, I'm also not clear how to specify a color using the given profile; e.g. rgb(15,15,15), but interpreted under the other profile.

My understanding is that the color profile can be set for individual elements in SVG. Can it be set via svgwrite for individual elements, and optionally also for the entire document?